# regex not beginning with multiple word

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex which matches when a number doesn't begin with 447 or 07 or 7.

```
^((?!447|07|7).)*$
```

This regex excludes everything containing 447,07,7 however, I need it to only exclude when it begins with those numbers.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?!447|0?7)\d+$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zK1sL1/1)

The negative look-ahead restricts the `\d+` pattern, and does not allow the number to start with `447` or `07` or `7`.

If there the string may contain any characters after that, use

```
^(?!447|0?7).*$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/zK1sL1/2)

BTW, your regex has an anchored *[tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)* that just matches any string that has no `447` or `07` or `7`.

Also note that `.` matches any character but a newline. To allow matching a newline, use singleline mode, or `[\s\S]`.